# Cannot access global array and write it to csv

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

I'm new to javascript and especially node and would appreciate some help.

I have the following code which looks up delivery status for various packages. Everything works fine except the final step, which is writing the results to a CSV file using the `csv-writer` package from npm.

I process each line of the source CSV and populate an array with the results. The array is declared at the top of the file as a const (`final_result`) outside of any function. In my understanding, this means it can be accessed by all the functions in the code. Is this right?

The problem I'm having is that when I get to the final step (writing the results to a new CSV file), the `final_result` length is `0` and contains no data !

When I `console-log` in the first and second functions, there is data showing.I can also see the array being populated as each row is processed

What am I missing or is there a better way (best practice? ) to achieve this. Thanks.

```
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;
const yt = require('yodel-tracking');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

const final_result = []; // This is showing as empty at the end ?!

const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
  path: 'out.csv',
  header: [
    { id: 'Location', title: 'Location' },
    { id: 'Ref', title: 'Ref' },
    { id: 'Scan', title: 'Scan' },
    { id: 'Status', title: 'Status' }
  ]
});

//Functions in order of how they are called

//1 of 3
function run() {
  fs.createReadStream('yodeldata.csv')
    .on('error', () => console.log('error'))
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', row => {
      output(row); //calling function 2 of 3
    });
}

//2 of 3
function output(row) {
  yt(row['REF'], 'GB', function(err, result) {
    let data = result.parcel_tracking.parcel_status[0];
    if (!err) {
      let obj = {
        Ref: `${row['REF']}`,
        Location: `${data.location}`,
        Scan: `${data.scan_date} ${data.scan_time}`,
        Status: `${data.status_description}`
      };
      final_result.push(obj); //Pushing each result to the array here
      console.log(final_result.length); // I can see the length increasing sequentially here
    }
  });
}

//3 of 3
function resultToCsv() {
  console.log('Number of records to be written to csv: ' + final_result.length); // Why is this Zero ?? Expected an array of objects here
  csvWriter
    .writeRecords(final_result)
    .then(() => console.log('The CSV file was written successfully'));
}

//Function calls
run();
resultToCsv();
```

Comment: Does the run function contains some async methods?

Comment: @jared, thanks for your comment but that situation does not apply to this

Comment: @prov, my problem is right at the end when I get to writing the results to csv, not obtaining the data. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Nick — Yes it does. You call `run` which triggers a bunch of asynchronous stuff, then (before the asynchronous stuff has finished) you call `resultToCsv` while `final_result` is still an empty array.

Comment: That was exactly my thought, why it comes to this problem.
You have to wait that the run function has finished before you are calling resultToCsv

Answer (score 0):

This issue here is that when you do this:

```
run();
resultToCsv();
```

Those two functions are being called immediately. Because run() is using asynchronous methods, it won't have finished reading the stream before `resultToCsv()` is called. So you want to wait for the stream to be done being read before calling that.

```
function run() {
  fs.createReadStream('yodeldata.csv')
    .on('error', () => console.log('error'))
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', row => {
      output(row); //calling function 2 of 3
    })
    .on('close', resultToCsv);

}
```